# Rails create blog

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Blog where I show the posts of the post in 5 in 5 in difrente pages EXAMPLE

blog/1
first page 1,2,3,4,5

blog/2
second page 6,7,8,9,10

Without using gems

Comment: Rails is a gem, so... What's the question here?

Comment: Your question doesn't match the title..what are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

Given the limited information in the post and not wanting to use one of the gems that does this, you should probably use [each_slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice)

`@pages = Blogs.all.each_slice(5)`